# How to proceed the masked image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to draw the ellipse on the image and then mask that area which i did as shown in the image below

[image]

well every one knows the original image of `lena` so i am not uploading it :) , well i have `img A` of lena and mask imag which i uploaded is `img Mask` , now i want to perform function on image mask in the area other than filled area , How i can change the color of area other than masked/filled image , then i want to put the image of lena (only the area which is under filled ellipse) into the processed image mask (of which i change the color other than filled color) and then put the lena image which i masked into the image mask , how to perform that task as well , is there any function in opencv to do that

[image: This circle image into the proceed mask image]

This circle image into the proceed mask image

What i am actually trying to achieve is

[image]

Code Which i did is :

```
void main ()
{
Mat img = imread ("E:\\lena.jpg");
Mat mask = img.clone();
ellipse(mask,Point(img.cols/2,img.rows/2),Size(img.cols/2,img.rows/2),0,0,360,Scalar(255,255,255), CV_FILLED, 8,0);
Mat mask2;
inRange(mask, Scalar(255,255,255), Scalar(255,255,255), mask2);
mask.setTo(Scalar(255,0,0), mask2);
}
```

Edit
Result.jpg

[image]

Edit for Extra Help :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
int main()
{
cv::Mat img = imread ("E:\\lena.jpg");
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
cv::ellipse(mask,cv::Point(mask.cols/2,mask.rows/2),cv::Size(mask.cols/2,mask.rows/2),0,0,360,cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8,0);

cv::imshow("mask", mask);

cv::Mat result = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, img.type());
result.setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));

img.copyTo(result, mask);
cv::imshow("result", result);
cv::waitKey(-1);
return 0;
}
```

input:

[image]

computed mask:

[image]

result:

[image]

idea: create a black image and copy only the masked area to it. 
This is the line `img.copyTo(result, mask);`. openCV masks are 1-channel CV_8U images of same size as the image.

if you want to manipulate pixel only in the mask region in general, you can do it like this:

```
loop over y and x coordinate of the image
    if(mask.at<unsigned char>(cv::Point(x,y)) != 0)
        manipulate the pixel in img
    else
        do not manipulate the pixel
```

Here is another example where you can see different things:
1. how to create a background mask if you have a foreground mask
2. how to loop over foreground/background only and perform some tasks on those pixel
3. how to copy from images, using a mask

```
int main()
{
// load image:
cv::Mat img = cv::imread ("lena.jpg");

// create the foreground mask in form of an ellipse:
cv::Mat foregroundMask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
cv::ellipse(foregroundMask,cv::Point(foregroundMask.cols/2,foregroundMask.rows/2),cv::Size(foregroundMask.cols/2,foregroundMask.rows/2),0,0,360,cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8,0);

cv::Mat foreground = img.clone();

// create the background mask which is just everything that is not foreground
cv::imshow("mask", foregroundMask);
cv::Mat backgroundMask = 255-foregroundMask;

// create a background and give it some color. this could be another loaded image instead.
cv::Mat background = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
// give the background some color. here white for example.
background.setTo(cv::Scalar(255,255,255));

// do some computation on the background image, but only where the background mask is not zero!
for(int y=0; y<backgroundMask.rows; ++y)
    for(int x=0; x<backgroundMask.cols; ++x)
    {
        cv::Point pixelPos(x,y);
        if(backgroundMask.at<unsigned char>(pixelPos))
        {
            // manipulate the background
            // I choose to set every 8th pixel in a random color, you could do any filter or something:
            if(x%8 == 0)
            {
                // create random color
                cv::Vec3b randomColor(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
                // use .at<Vec3b> for 24 bit BGR values
                background.at<cv::Vec3b>(pixelPos) = randomColor;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // you could process any pixel here which is NOT in your background mask, but I'll process foreground explicitly later
        }
    }


// just in case that you want to modify the foreground too, here's an example:
for(int y=0; y<foregroundMask.rows; ++y)
        for(int x=0; x<foregroundMask.cols; ++x)
        {
            cv::Point pixelPos(x,y);
            if(foregroundMask.at<unsigned char>(pixelPos))
            {
                // manipulate the background
                // for example, set every 12th row to blue color:
                if(y%12 == 0)
                {
                    // create random color
                    cv::Vec3b blueColor(255, 0, 0);
                    // use .at<Vec3b> for 24 bit BGR values
                    foreground.at<cv::Vec3b>(pixelPos) = blueColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // you could process any pixel here which is NOT in your foreground mask, but I've processed background explicitly earlier
            }
        }


cv::imshow("modified background", background);
cv::imshow("modified foreground", foreground);

// this is how to copy something using masks:

cv::Mat result;
// copy background masked pixel from background image to the result:
background.copyTo(result, backgroundMask);
// copy foreground masked pixel from foreground image to the result:
foreground.copyTo(result, foregroundMask);


cv::imshow("result", result);
cv::waitKey(-1);
return 0;
}
```

This is how the images look like:

input like before:

[image]

foreground mask: it's just the ellipse that we painted:

[image]

background mask: it's all that is not foreground:

[image]

the original background image is just a white image in my example.
this is the modified background image, where some of the masked background images are modified and everything that is not in the background mask is unmodified (see code):

[image]

now the modified foreground image, see that no pixel that is not masked as foreground isn modified

[image]

and finally after using the `.copyTo()` with using masks:

[image]

you can see easily that you dont even have to copy both of the images, if you copy one into the other and many other easy simplifications are possible, that code is just to demonstrate how you can use masks in many different ways.

hope it helps and you can do whatever you want after understanding the code =)

Comment: What if i don't want computed maska background not to b black , i just want it to b the orignal background !! just the ellipse as filled

Comment: then do it as said after the images, loop over the mask and manipulate (set color) only in the original images' pixel where the mask is set. Or (might be more efficient): `cv::Mat mask2 = 255-mask; background.copyTo(img, mask2)` then you copy only the background to the image.

Comment: or: `img.copyTo(backgroundImage, mask);`

Comment: may be you didn't noticed my first image in the question , its filled area is blue but background is as it is , now i want to apply further filtering algorithm on its that orignal background , after applying the filtering on it , i will than fix the masked image in that image , hope you get my point now

Comment: ok, you want to edit the image wherever your mask isnt blue (with some filter for example) and the rest of the image (where your mask is blue) should not be changed? I'm still not sure how your result should look like.

Comment: @Ahmad : edited the answer to give you some more ways/code how to use masks. I think you can achieve what you want after understanding what is done in that code (there are many comments).

Comment: Thankyou , +1 , actually i am trying to make vignette out of it

Comment: What if i want to make the ellipse area transparent and hollow and other remain the same

Comment: there is no transparency, but you can compute whatever image you want and later copy the areas which should remain the same with the according mask (which would be the "backgroundMask" in that scenario or 255-foregroundMask). `remainSamePartsImage.copyTo(newImage,backgroundMask);`

Comment: i just it to be of frame type whose corners are black and center is empty , is it possible with opencv ?